# I need to modify the placeholder in Swagger. The current placeholder matches the one specified in property for swagger . How can I resolve this issue?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, swagger-editor

[In the image provided, the property is defined as recipient[name], resulting in the usage of the same placeholder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hj3Pv.png)
[Could you please review the code I've referenced? I'm looking to make adjustments to acquire a different placeholder. Are there any specific changes needed for this purpose?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4F1Cf.png)

I'm hopeful that my issue will be resolved as anticipated; I simply need a different placeholder.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.